How can I combine two plots having different parameters in y axis and same parameter in x axis?
I have two separate plots with the same parameter in the x-axis ($\phi$) and different parameters ($m_1$ and $m_2$) in the y-axis. I want to combine the plots and plot them in a single graph with ($m_1$, $m_2$) in the y-axis.
It will be very helpful if you kindly help me how to do it.
m1[ϕ_, m21_, β_, α_, θ_, r_] := 
  Sqrt[m21] √((((-(2 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Cos[2 α Degree] + 3 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Cos[
                 2 (α + ϕ) Degree]) (2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 β Degree] + 
              3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[
                2 (β + ϕ) Degree]) + (3 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 (α + ϕ) Degree] + 
              2 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 α Degree]) (2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Cos[
                2 β Degree] + 
              3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Cos[
                2 (β + ϕ) Degree]))/(2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 β Degree] + 
           3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[
             2 (β + ϕ) Degree]))^2)/(1 - ((-(2 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Cos[2 α Degree] + 
                3 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Cos[
                  2 (α + ϕ) Degree]) (2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 β Degree] + 
               3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[
                 2 (β + ϕ) Degree]) + (3 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 (α + ϕ) Degree] +                
               2 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[
                 2 α Degree]) (2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Cos[
                 2 β Degree] + 
               3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Cos[
                 2 (β + ϕ) Degree]))/(2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 β Degree] + 
            3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[
              2 (β + ϕ) Degree]))^2));
Tab6 = Table[{ϕ, m1[ϕ, Random[Real, {0.000068, 0.000084}], 
     Random[Real, {0 , 360}], Random[Real, {0, 360}], 
     Random[Real, {14.26 , 15.64}], 
     Random[Real, {0.026, 0.034}]]}, {ϕ, 40 , 315 , 1 Degree }];
Tab7 = DeleteCases[Tab6, {_?(116 < # < 239 &), _}];
P4 = ListPlot[Tab7, Frame -> { True, True, True, True}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.1}, FrameLabel -> {ϕ, Subscript[m, 1]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, PlotMarkers -> "+", PlotStyle -> Red,
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, Bold, 13]]


m2[ϕ_, m21_, β_, α_, θ_, r_] := 
  Sqrt[m21] √(1/((1 - ((-(2 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Cos[2 α Degree] + 
                 3 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Cos[
                   2 (α + ϕ) Degree]) (2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 β Degree] + 
                3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[
                  2 (β + ϕ) Degree]) + (3 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 (α + ϕ) Degree] + 
                2 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[
                  2 α Degree]) (2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Cos[2 β Degree] + 
                3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Cos[
                  2 (β + ϕ) Degree]))/(2 Sin[θ Degree]^2 Sin[2 β Degree] + 
             3 Cos[θ Degree]^2 Sin[
               2 (β + ϕ) Degree]))^2)));
Tab8 =  Table[{ϕ, m2[ϕ, Random[Real, {0.000068, 0.000084}], 
     Random[Real, {0 , 360}], Random[Real, {0, 360}], 
     Random[Real, {14.26 , 15.64}], 
     Random[Real, {0.026, 0.034}]]}, {ϕ, 40 , 315 , 1 Degree }];
Tab9 =DeleteCases[Tab8, {_?(116 < # < 239 &), _}];
P5 = ListPlot[Tab9, Frame -> { True, True, True, True}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.1}, FrameLabel -> {ϕ, Subscript[m, 2]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14} , PlotMarkers -> "*", 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, Bold, 13]]



Look at "https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html"

The two vertical axes are the same in this case (they run from 0 to 0.1 with labeled ticks every 0.02 units, and minor ticks every 0.005 units). Would it be acceptable to just have a vertical axis labeled "m" and a legend showing which one is m1 and which one is m2 like this?

Thank you so much for helping. But how can I place the legend on the top corner on the right/left rather than the center of the graph?

You can change PlotLegends -> Placed[Framed[leg], Center]  in my definition of of P5 to PlotLegends -> Placed[Framed[leg], {Right, Top}] but you might have to increase the PlotRange because the legend overlaps with the data when I put it in the top right
